# Sort articles by most comments

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, one-to-many

I have two tables `articles` and `comments`. The have one to many relationship. An article has many comments and the other side a comment is belongs to an article. Now I want to sort all articles according to most comments.

Here is the table schema:

**articles**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->date('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**comments**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('blog_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('comment_id')->nullable(); //parent comment's id if any
        $table->text('message');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('blog_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('articles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
    });
}
```

Here is the relationship code:

**Article**

```
/**
 * An article has many comments
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Comment**

```
/**
 * A comment is belongs to an article
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}
```

Any help will be appreciable.

> I preferred the solution in Eloquent way. If not possible other way will also OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as:

```
Article::withCount('comments')->orderBy('comments_count')->get();
```

`withCount()` method is used when you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

Comment: Thanks bro. `withCount()` method is new for me.